# I got problem to run JSP and Servlet on Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, macos-big-sur

I got a problem to run JSP file on Apache Netbeans 12.3 JDK 16.0 and I am using tomcat 9.0.45 on macOS BigSur. I'm not sure what is the problem actually. Could you please help me.And when I run the servlet file I got this error message.

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.netbeans.modules.tomcat5.deploy.TomcatManagerImpl (in unnamed module @0x19f724b9) cannot access class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64 (in module java.xml) because module java.xml does not export com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util to unnamed module @0x19f724b9
    at org.netbeans.modules.tomcat5.deploy.TomcatManagerImpl.run(TomcatManagerImpl.java:533)
    at org.netbeans.modules.tomcat5.deploy.TomcatManagerImpl.list(TomcatManagerImpl.java:372)
    at org.netbeans.modules.tomcat5.deploy.TomcatManager.modules(TomcatManager.java:718)
    at org.netbeans.modules.tomcat5.deploy.TomcatManager.getAvailableModules(TomcatManager.java:529)
    at org.netbeans.modules.tomcat5.optional.TMIDResolver.lookupTargetModuleID(TMIDResolver.java:56)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.TargetServer.checkUndeployForSharedReferences(TargetServer.java:349)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.TargetServer.checkUndeployForSharedReferences(TargetServer.java:322)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.TargetServer.checkUndeployForSharedReferences(TargetServer.java:319)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.TargetServer.processLastTargetModules(TargetServer.java:440)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.TargetServer.init(TargetServer.java:170)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.TargetServer.deploy(TargetServer.java:605)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:221)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:141)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.ant.Deploy.execute(Deploy.java:86)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor59.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1391)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1254)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:261)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:574)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.doRun(RunClassThread.java:132)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:45)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:278)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:81)
```

Comment: Do you use JPMS (java 9+ modules)?

Comment: I am not sure about that. How to check it ?

Comment: Is there a file named `module-info.java`?

Comment: I have look on it and yes I got the file

Comment: Researching this issue is pointless since your environment is invalid; NetBeans 12.3 does not support JDK 16. Update your question if the problem persists when using JDK 15, which is supported.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 9, the Java Platform Module System has been introduced.

This also adds access rules.

In your case, the module `java.xml` does not export `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64` but tomcat tries to access it nevertheless (The version of tomcat you are using may not support JPMS).

Here are three different approaches you could try:

#### Update Tomcat

Newer versions of tomcat might have fixed this issue. For example, tomcat 10 seems to support JPMS.

#### Add `--add-exports java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util=ALL-UNNAMED` to the JVM arguments.

When starting tomcat, you can add the JVM argument `--add-exports java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util=ALL-UNNAMED` to the command that starts tomcat. As tomcat is likely started via a script, this behaviour might be controlled with environment variables. Many scripts use the environment variable`JAVA_OPTS` for this. If you set the environment variable `JAVA_OPTS` to `--add-exports java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util=ALL-UNNAMED` (or add that to the environment variable) before starting tomcat, it might get picked up. Alternatively, you can manually add it to the command or use an environment variable like `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` that gets picked up by the JVM automatically.

This configures the module java.xml to export the package to all unnamed modules (including tomcat) even if it does not do that by default.

See [Java Platform, Standard Edition Oracle JDK 9 Migration Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-12F945EB-71D6-46AF-8C3D-D354FD0B1781)

> If you need to use an internal API that has been made inaccessible, then use the `--add-exports` runtime option. You can also use `--add-exports` at compile time to access internal APIs.

See [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/java.html) on details what `--add-exports` does.

#### Remove the `module-info.java`

By doing this, Java could fall back to the old non-JPMS behaviour.

Comment: for the Add --add-exports java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util=ALL-UNNAMED to the JVM arguments (e.g. using JAVA_OPTS). . I don't really understand it. may you explain it

Comment: When you start tomcat, you start a java program. This is done using something like `java -jar tomcat.jar`. You can add the `--add-exports` jvm argument before the JAR, there. As tomcat is likely started by a script, you may want to add the option to the environment variable `JAVA_OPTS` as many such scripts append the content of this environment variable to the JVM arguments.

Answer (score -1):

NetBeans 12.3 does not support JDK 16, so what you were attempting to do is unsupported.

Refer to the section on [Deployment Platforms](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb123/nb123.html) in the NetBeans 12.3 documentation:

> Apache NetBeans 12.3 runs on JDK LTS releases 8 and 11, as well as on
> JDK 15, i.e., the current JDK release at the time of this NetBeans
> release.

So try replacing JDK 16 in your NetBeans configuration with JDK 15, to see if the problem goes away. If the issue persists using Java 15 then update your question by replacing the JDK 16 stack trace with a JDK 15 stack trace.

As a related matter, since you mentioned that you are using Big Sur, you may also want to review NetBeans Bug Report [NETBEANS-5037 NetBeans dialog windows in Big Sur](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-5037). That may not be relevant for you, but it is also mentioned in the NetBeans 12.3 release documentation:

> The current JDKs have an issue on macOS Big Sur, that causes freezes
> on dialogs. That could be fixed by applying the workaround described
> at NETBEANS-5037.

Comment: how to change from jdk 16 to 15 like automatically. Because if I do it manually at the properties of the web file. my netbeans will lag and I need to re open the netbeans. and then after I run the JSP nothing happens. but when I run the full project, I got the error as I showed in the question.

Comment: @NURMAHDIAHSALEH You can't "change from jdk 16 to 15 like automatically"...you have to download/install JDK 15, then add JDK 15 as a Java Platform in NetBeans, then rebuild/redeploy your web project using JDK 15 instead of JDK 16. But the steps needed for JDK 15 are no different to those you have already taken for JDK 16. Or am I misunderstanding your concern?

Comment: how to change it ? in the terminal ?

Comment: @ No. Step 1: Download and install JDK 15. Step 2: Add that as a Java Platform within NetBeans using **Tools > Java Platforms > Add Platform...** Step 3: Rebuild your project using JDK 15 instead of JDK 16. The way to do that varies according to your build tool (Ant, Maven etc.) Step 4: Redeploy your JDK 15 application to Tomcat. But surely you have already done all this using Java 16, right? The steps for JDK 15 are exactly the same as those for JDK 16.